# regarding HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: internet-explorer, user-agent

Have a perl CGI script that display the CGI environment variable.
In IE8 getting the HTTP_USER_AGENT Value for IE 8 as MSIE 7.0.  Why it's not displaying MSIE 8.0?

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1;
WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB7.5; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)
```

Comment: If it's a perl script, why are you tagging the question PHP?

Comment: Has nothing to do with Perl either. Perl is just repeating the web server which is just repeating the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is probably in Compatibility View mode. Click the button outlined in the image below (looks like a page ripped in half, next to the reload button) to disable it.

[image: Compatibility View button]